# jQuery -> open a new smaller window in a window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website and there is an image on it. What I want: If I click on the image, I want to open a window inside this window. I often see this with images, I want to show in a bigger size.

I have a thumbnail on the site and then by clicking it, the background will be grey and the image opens in a layer on top of the site with the big image.

I want the same, if it is possible with jQuery, and I want to display a bigger image and some text. How can this be done with jQuery?

Best Regards.

Comment: Use fancybox. It was build using jquery library. http://fancybox.net/

Comment: Checkout the Lightbox jquery: http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is create a `modal dialog` which is usually just a container with the appropriate CSS that makes it sit on top of the other HTML on the page.

There are hundreds of jQuery plug ins to do this. Here's an article describing 19 of them:

[19 jQuery Modal Boxes to Improve your UI](http://coderplus.com/2009/11/jquery-modal-boxes-to-improve-your-ui/) - Nov 1, 2009

[jQuery Modal Box Round Up](http://komunitasweb.com/2009/03/jquery-modal-box-round-up/) - Mar 16, 2009

[Top 10 jQuery Modal Box Plugins](http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/top-10-jquery-modal-box-plugins/) - Dec 29, 2009

*2009, the year of the "my preferred modal dialog" blog posts*

---

Ones I've used and like:

- **jQuery UI Dialog** is pretty solid and customizable: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog
- **FancyBox** is very simple and easy to use: http://fancybox.net/
- **LightBox 2** is a nice modal: http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Answer (score 1):

you're probably thinking of [lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) or something similar

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for [jquery lightBox plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/).

some ways to use it are the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // Use this example, or...
    $('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox(); // Select all links that contains lightbox in the attribute rel
    // This, or...
    $('#gallery a').lightBox(); // Select all links in object with gallery ID
    // This, or...
    $('a.lightbox').lightBox(); // Select all links with lightbox class
    // This, or...
    $('a').lightBox(); // Select all links in the page
    // ... The possibility are many. Use your creative or choose one in the examples above
});
</script>
```

For more information visit the link above.

An alternative is [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) or any jquery plugin for [photo gallery](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=jquery+photo+gallery&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=).

Comment: But how can I design that I will have an image opened and text on the right side of the image... and some other HTML stuff?

Comment: @Tim I am not sure what you mean when you say "design"? Follow the examples in the documentation of each plugin to check how it works, and then modify it according your needs. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yep try a simple solution: [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)! Enjoy, I'm sure this will go a long way with what you want from your website, and its easy to integrate! And yes this requires jQuery, and has nicer functionality than native jQuery lightbox component.

Answer (score 1):

you can use http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/, it is jQuery plugin

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like the [ThickBox plugin](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/). Go to the link and click "Examples" then "Demo".

There is also [LightBox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) with is an alternative jQuery plugin.